# How to get server IP-address in an Angular application?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

How to get the server host IP-address in Angular app started with `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`?

The IP-Adress will be used when communicate with the backend server.

Since each coworker has its own IP-Address I should like to avoid to have it hardcoded in the code. I can´t use localhost either since then my coworkers can´t access it.

Is angular running completely on client side or is it possible to add something to fetch the IP-Address when the application get the first request?

Comment: You can't do it on the first request because there will be none if the client doesn't know the IP address

Comment: It should be okay for me to print it when the server is started. However I don´t want IP-address hardcoded in the git repo. Since each team member need to update it. But if I want someone to test it I can send them my IP-adress on teams. Its not that often our IP-Adress change.

Comment: In our team we use environment-variable to solve this:
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-use-environment-variable-in-angularexample.html
But it should be nice to automatically look up the server ip.

Comment: When using AJAX/WSS you can also consider to use a relative path instead of a full URL - e.g. `/api/test` instead of `http://10.0.1.1/api/test`

Comment: The backend server is running on another port than frontend. In production it also run on another server where the domain name is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hostname in angular using `window.location.hostname` . This will be ip address if your app does not have a domain name. Otherwise this will be the domain name:

E.g:

```
http://test.com   ---> test.com

http://192.168.1.1  ---> 192.168.1.1
```

Then you can include this `window.location.hostname` in `environment.ts` files of angular like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  backend: {
    apiUrlV1: 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080/api/v1/',
    oauthUrl: 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':8080/'
  }
....
};
```

You can build the angular app and copy the build files to your local server. Your co developer can also do the same build in his local machine and deploy in his local server.

You can also access the backend even if you use domain name (e.g: if apiUrlV1 becomes `http://test.com:8080/api/v1/`). To enable this, you have to map the domain name to the backend via reverse proxy. For eg:

If you use nginx in `nginx.conf` config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /<path to your app build files>/html; #keep build files inside html folder. This comment is for info. Remove this comment entirely
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name test.com 192.168.1.1;  #use space to separate multiple entries here. Then requests with any of these addresses in header will be proxied to this routing. This comment is for info. Remove this comment entirely.

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api;
        }

        location /oauth {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/oauth;
        }

.....
}
```

Now, if the user use `http://test.com` OR `http://192.168.1.1`  in browser, the api requests from browser will be routed back to `http://test.com/v1/api` OR to `http://192.168.1.1/v1/api` . The backend reverse proxy will map it to localhost accordingly.